# should admin-only fields be extracted into a dedicated model which has a OneToOne relation to the original model?

Tags: python, django, orm, database-normalization

I have the following model

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    # other fields...
    billing_active = models.BooleanField(
        _('Billing active'),
        default=True,
        help_text=_(
            'designates whether the user should be charged'
        )
    )
    billing_start = models.DateField(_('Billing cycle start'))
    billing_end = models.DateField(_('Billing cycle end'))
    billing_charge = models.DecimalField(
        _('Charge'),
        max_digits=5,
        decimal_places=2,
        help_text='amount to be charged'
    )
```

by looking at those prefixes `billing_*` it seems that fields should belong to a new object, it seems OK since it's just a database representation. But `billing_active` and `billing_charge` are admin fields and can't be changed by user, would it be good to create a new model `UserBillingSettings` which contains all those fields? then I could use django's builtin permissions system:

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    # fields ...

class UserBillingSettings(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='billing_settings')
    # billing fields
    class Meta:
        permissions = (('can_change', 'Change user billing settings'),)
```

Comment: What do you think this has to do with DB normalization? (It doesn't just mean "good design" or "more tables".)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are absolutely right, you always need to separate such details -*Not directly related to the Users table*, into their own table.

```
class BillingInfo(models.Model):
    billing_active = models.BooleanField(
        _('Billing active'),
        default=True,
        help_text=_(
            'designates whether the user should be charged'
        )
    )
    billing_start = models.DateField(_('Billing cycle start'))
    billing_end = models.DateField(_('Billing cycle end'))
    billing_charge = models.DecimalField(
        _('Charge'),
        max_digits=5,
        decimal_places=2,
        help_text='amount to be charged'
    )
    ...
    class Meta:
        permissions = (('can_change', 'Change user billing settings'),)

class User(AbstractUser):
    ... user info
    billing_info = models.OneToOneField(BillingInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I will keep the reference from `BillingInfo` to `User` because `BillingInfo` is a weak entity (it can't exist without a user)

Comment: since there is a OneToOneRelation between User and BillingInfo, you can always access user from a BillingInfo object, Django Adds a property to access it. `billing_info_obj.user`, it will throw DoesNotExist exception if it is not related to a User.